# jump to another (separate) function on else statement

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( // condition ) {
        //do stuff
    }
    else ( // how do you jump to another separate function from this else statement? ) {};
});
```

for example: I have another function (jump). and I want to run the function after else statement and I dont want it inside the previous code.

```
function jump(e) {
    // blah blah
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by jump to another function?

Comment: just call `jump()` in the else portion

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function from the else condition.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke the `jump` method in the `else` portion

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( condition ) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        jump();
    }
});
```